# How to do multiple joins on the same table with the same source with same column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having trouble visualizing how to approach this problem I have. I would like to join the same column from the same source multiple times to the same table.

I need a way to create a new column with a filter applied per product type.

The issue is that the table being joined contains the data as such:
The item_numbers are repeated per product_type so its all stacked into one column and needs to be separated.

| item_number | product_type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | A | 3 |
| 2 | B | 1 |
| 3 | B | 2 |
| 4 | A | 6 |
| 5 | A | 5 |
| 5 | B | 7 |

This was my attempt which didn't work. I'm pretty new so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT 
    tableA.item_number,
    tableB.item_number,
    tableB.product_type,
    tableB.quantity AS productA_qty,
    tableB.quantity AS productB_qty
FROM 
    tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tableB ON tableA.item_number = tableB.item_number 
WHERE 
    product_type = 'A'
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    bom ON tableA.item_number = tableB.item_number 
WHERE 
    product_type = 'B'
```

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Comment: It looks like you're expecting the `WHERE` clause to limit the results of the `JOIN`, which err... does work sometimes, but I think you're better off with `... AND tableB.product_type = 'A'` instead.

Comment: @SwaD Looking to get a table with the item_number and quantity, but there will be multiple quantity columns with a specific filter on each (one product type filted on each - A, B, C, etc.).

Comment: @sj95126 this worked, but I can't reference the quantity column twice? How do I define the 2 joins from the same source column with different filters as individual columns in the resulting table?

Comment: Without you updating your question to show the actual result you want to achieve then it’s difficult to help, but it looks like you want to pivot your data which would require using the CROSSTAB function

Answer (score 0):

You should use SUM aggregation per item_number and separate the columns by product_type:

```
SELECT
    item_number,
    sum(case when product_type = 'A' then quantity else 0 end) as product_a_quantity,
    sum(case when product_type = 'B' then quantity else 0 end) as product_b_quantity
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```